# robocopy extra files move to another folder

Tags: batch-file, filesystems, dos, robocopy

I am trying to write a batch to copy all files (those in subfolders too) from directory1 to directory2 and then moving any extra files (or directories if possible) found in directory2 to directory3.
In other words, I am trying to mirror directory2 with directory1 but instead of the purge action, moving the extra files to directory3...

So far, I've been able to get those extra files in a text file... Now, I don't know how to proceed...

```
ROBOCOPY directory1 directory2 /E /COPYALL /R:0 /XO /X /tee /njh /njs /np /ns /nc /ndl > Extrafiles.txt
```

Further, the Extrafiles.txt does contain a lot of extra spaces at start of each file path that means a little string manipulation before moving the file. And which command to use to move the files by automatically creating the target directory if it does not exist?

Sample output of Extrafiles.txt

```
                directory2\File1.txt
                directory2\subdirectory2\deeper\File2.txt
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Making it a little more clear:

Suppose directory1 contains:

```
\subdir1
    file4.txt
    file5.txt
    \deeper
        file6.txt
        file7.doc
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

and directory2 already contains:

```
\subdir1
    file4.txt
    file007.ppt
    \deeper
        file6.txt
        file7.doc
        \deepest
            file155.txt
file1.txt
```

Then I want these files to be copied:

```
directory1\file2.txt to directory2\file2.txt
directory1\subdir1\file5.txt to directory2\subdir1\file5.txt
```

And then these files to be moved:

```
directory2\subdir1\file007.ppt to directory3\subdir1\file007.ppt
directory2\subdir1\deeper\deepest\file155.txt to directory3\subdir1\deeper\deepest\file155.txt
```

Hope I made it clear enough :)

Comment: I think you should be able to do everything you want simply by using ROBOCOPY. But I don't fully understand your requirements. If you provide a listing of what a small hypothetical directory1, 2 and 3 (including at least one subdirectory for each) might look like, and then show what they should look like after the operation is complete - then I or someone else might be better able to help you.

Comment: editted! please check back...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` to iterate through the contents of the file generated by `robocopy` (see `for /?`).

Then you can use delayed expansion and variable substitution to generate the target path (see `set /?`), and finally call a subroutine that will do `mkdir` if needed followed by `move` (see `call /?`).

A draft solution would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set srcdir=directory2
set tgtdir=directory3

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("Extrafiles.txt") do (
  set srcpath=%%A
  set tgtpath=!srcpath:%srcdir%=%tgtdir%!
  call :mkdirmove !srcpath! !tgtpath!
)

goto :EOF

:mkdirmove
  if not exist %~dp2nul mkdir %~dp2
  move %1 %2
goto :EOF
```